# Como puedo hacer una lista de objetos que sean de una cierta clase?

Tags: c++

Se supone que tenemos que ir leyendo un txt con instrucciones, cada vez que leamos algo del estilo  "Int A" se tiene que crear un objeto de una clase llamada "Variables" para poder meterla luego en una lista de objetos "Variables", el problema está en que hice la lista, hice la clase Variables y todo por separado anda, cuando le digo que quiero que la lista sea de "Variables" me tira error y estoy clavado ahí, particularmente el error es este.

```
TP.cpp: In instantiation of 'Nodo<T>::Nodo() [with T = Variable]':
TP.cpp:125:15:   required from 'Lista<T>::Lista() [with T = Variable]'
TP.cpp:264:46:   required from here
TP.cpp:96:11: error: no matching function for call to 'Variable::Variable()'
   96 |     Nodo(){
      |           ^
TP.cpp:26:1: note: candidate: 'Variable::Variable(int, std::string, std::string)'
   26 | Variable::Variable(int d, string t, string n){
      | ^~~~~~~~
TP.cpp:26:1: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
TP.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: 'Variable::Variable(const Variable&)'
    7 | class Variable{
      |       ^~~~~~~~
TP.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

y mi código es este:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Variable{
    private:
        int dato;//se empleara para aquellos que sean de tipo bool 0 para false y 1 para true
        string tipo;
        string nomb;
    public:
        Variable(int d, string t, string n);//constructor del objeto
        ~Variable();

        void set_nomb(string n);
        void set_tipo(string t);
        void set_dato(int d);

        string get_tipo();
        string get_nomb();
        int get_dato();
};//fin de la clase variable

//implementacion de los objetos variable
Variable::Variable(int d, string t, string n){
    set_nomb(n);
    set_tipo(t);
    set_dato(d);
    cout<<"Objeto variable creado con exito"<<endl;
}

Variable::~Variable(){
}

void Variable::set_nomb(string n){
    nomb=n;
}

void Variable::set_tipo(string t){
    tipo=t;
}

void Variable::set_dato(int d){
    dato=d;
}

string Variable::get_nomb(){
    return nomb;
}

string Variable::get_tipo(){
    return tipo;
}

int Variable::get_dato(){
    return dato;
}

//clase objetos instruccion

class Instruccion{
    private:
        string dato;//se empleara para aquellos que sean de tipo bool 0 para false y 1 para true
    public:
        Instruccion(string t);//constructor del objeto
        ~Instruccion();

        void set_instruct(string d);
        string get_instruct();
        void ejecutar();
};//fin de la clase variable

//implementacion de los objetos variable
Instruccion::Instruccion(string d){
    set_instruct(d);
    cout<<"Objeto instruccion creado con exito"<<endl;
}

Instruccion::~Instruccion(){
}

void Instruccion::set_instruct(string d){
    dato=d;
}

string Instruccion::get_instruct(){
    return dato;
}

template <class T> class Nodo {
private:
    T dato;
    Nodo* next;
public:
    Nodo(){ 
        next = NULL; 
    };
    Nodo(T a){ 
        dato = a; 
        next = NULL; 
    };
    void set_dato(T a){ 
        dato = a; 
    };
    void set_next(Nodo* n) { 
        next = n; 
    };
    T get_dato(){ 
        return dato;
    };
    Nodo* get_next(){ 
        return next; 
    };
    bool es_vacio(){ 
        return next == NULL; 
    }
};

template <class T> class Lista {
private: Nodo<T>* czo;
     
public:
    Lista() { 
        czo = new Nodo<T>(); 
    };
    Lista(Nodo<T>* n){ 
        czo = n; 
    };
    //~Lista(void);
    void add(T d); //sumar nodos a la lista
    bool esvacia(void);
    T cabeza(void); //retorna el dato del primer nodo
    Lista* resto(void); //retorna el puntero al "resto" de la lista
                        //resto= lo que queda de la lista sin la cabeza
    string toPrint(string p);
    T suma(T i);
    int size();
    void borrar(void); //borra la cabeza
    void borrar_last();//borra el ultimo
    void concat(Lista<T>* l1);// le transfiere los datos de l1 a this
    Lista<T>* copy(void);// hace una copia de la lista
    void tomar(int n);//deja "vivos" los n primeros nodos y borra el resto
    void addOrdenado(T d);// suma nodos ordenados de menor a mayor
    bool esta(T d); //retorna true cuando d est� en la lista
    void borrarDato(T d);// borra el nodo que contiene a d
   
};
template <class T>
void Lista<T>::add(T d) //100
{
    Nodo<T>* nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);
    nuevo->set_next(czo);
    czo = nuevo;
}
template <class T>
bool Lista<T>::esvacia(void)
{
    return czo->es_vacio();
}
template <class T>
T Lista<T>::cabeza(void)
{
    if (this->esvacia()) {
        cout << " Error, Cabeza de lista vacia";
        return NULL;
    }
    return czo->get_dato();
}

template <class T>
Lista<T>* Lista<T>::resto(void)
{
    Lista* l = new Lista(czo->get_next());
    return (l);
}

template <class T>
string Lista<T>::toPrint(string p)
{
    if (this->esvacia()) {
        return p;
    }
    else {
        //std::ostringstream stm;
        ostringstream stm;
        stm << this->cabeza() << "-" << this->resto()->toPrint(p) << endl;
        //cout<<endl<<" stm.str()= "<<stm.str()<<endl;
        return stm.str();
    }
}

template <class T>
T Lista<T>::suma(T i)
{    //cout<<" i al entrar= "<<i<<endl;
    if (this->esvacia()) {
        return i;
    }
    else {

        //cout<<"this->cabeza()= "<<this->cabeza()<<endl;   
        return this->resto()->suma(i + this->cabeza());
    }
}

template <class T> int Lista<T>::size()
{
    if (this->esvacia()) return 0;
    return 1 + this->resto()->size();
}



template <class T> void Lista<T>::borrar(void)
{ //borra el nodo cabeza
    if (!this->esvacia()) {
        Nodo<T>* tmp = czo;
        czo = czo->get_next();
        delete tmp;
    }
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::borrar_last()
{ // borra el ultimo nodo
    if (!this->esvacia()) {
        if ((czo->get_next())->get_next() == NULL) {
            delete czo->get_next();
            czo->set_next(NULL);
        }
        else this->resto()->borrar_last();
    }
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::concat(Lista<T>* l1)
{// le transfiere los datos de l1 a this
    if (!(l1->esvacia())) {
        this->concat(l1->resto());
        this->add(l1->cabeza());
    }
}

template <class T> Lista<T>* Lista<T>::copy(void)
{
    Lista<T>* aux = new Lista();
    aux->concat(this);
    return aux;
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::tomar(int n)
{ //deja "vivos" los n primeros nodos y borra el resto
    if (this->size() > n) {
        this->borrar_last();
        this->tomar(n);
    }
}

int numero;
string tipos;
string nombre;
int i=0;
int cant;
int main()
{
    Lista<Variable>* l = new Lista<Variable>();
   
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de objetos que queres en la lista: "<<endl;
    cin>>cant;
    while(i<=cant){
        cout<<"Ingrese un valor: "<<endl;
        cin>>numero;
        cout<<"Ingrese un tipo: "<<endl;
        cin>>tipos;
        cout<<"Ingrese un nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>nombre;
        Variable t(numero,tipos,nombre);
        l->add(t);
        i++;
    }
    
    cout<<"Si funciona deberia haber la cant de nodos como cant de ojetos quisiste meter"<<endl;
    cout<<"La cantidad de objetos es: "<< l->size();



  

}
```

Disculpen si el formato no es el adecuado, es mi primera vez publicando acá, muchas gracias

Comment: A primera vista, el constructor de Variable requiere de un int y dos std::string, y en esta línea ```
    Lista<Variable>* l = new Lista<Variable>();
   ``` intentas crear un objeto sin argumentos.

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias 

Comment: Si no es necesario que crees tus propias estructuras, puedes usar un `vector` y no tendrás el problema del constructor, porque puedes usar `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'Nodo<T>::Nodo() [with T = Variable]':
>       required from 'Lista<T>::Lista() [with T = Variable]'
> error: no matching function for call to 'Variable::Variable()'
> ```

> ```
> Instanciando 'Nodo<T>::Nodo() [con T = Variable]':
>       requerido en 'Lista<T>::Lista() [con T = Variable]'
> error: no se encuentra una función coincidente para llamar 'Variable::Variable()'
> ```

Te está diciendo que intenta llamar al constructor de `Variable` sin argumentos (`'Variable::Variable()'`) al construir un nodo (`Instanciando 'Nodo<T>::Nodo()'`) al crear una lista (`requerido en 'Lista<T>::Lista()`) pero no le es posible hacerlo porque no encuentra dicho constructor, lo cuál es cierto:

```
class Variable{
...
...
    public:
        Variable(int d, string t, string n);//constructor del objeto
        ~Variable();
...
...
};
```

No existe un constructor de `Variable` sin argumentos, la siguiente corrección debería solucionar ese problema:

```
class Variable{
    private:
        int dato = 0;
        string tipo;
        string nomb;
    public:
        Variable(int d, string t, string n);
        Variable() = default; // Constructor sin argumentos.

        void set_nomb(const string &n);
        void set_tipo(const string &t);
        void set_dato(int d);

        const string &get_tipo() const;
        const string &get_nomb() const;
        int get_dato() const;
};
```

La línea `Variable() = default;` le pide al compilador que cree el constructor por defecto de la clase `Variable`, dado que iba a ser un constructor sin nada en el cuerpo<sup>1</sup> no necesitamos redactarlo (¡que lo haga el compilador!), he eliminado el destructor (`~Variable()`) porque esta clase no lo necesita. En los *setters* he cambiado los parámetros por referencias constantes para evitar hacer copias de datos innecesarias y he cambiado los *getters* para que devuelvan referencias constantes por el mismo motivo y he marcado las funciones `get_xxx` como constantes porque no modifican el objeto al que pertenecen.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Todas las variables miembro ya se inicializan por defecto ya que `string` tiene constructor por defecto y `dato` se inicializa a cero en el punto de declaración.

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo con el tema de los punteros así que me costó entender pero me quedó super claro, muchas gracias